# How does spring connection pool work at the physical level?

Tags: java, spring

For instance, I have a setting:

```
spring.datasource.maxActive=5
```

1. Does it mean that after Spring has started, 5 active physical connections have been created in the pool? Or are they just objects?
2. Will the physical connection to the database be created after accessing the pool?
3. If all 5 connection are be busy, Will the connection pool create new connection and put it to the pool?
4. Where is the middle ground? How to calculate the volume of the pool?

Comment: Do you use DBCP connection pool?

Comment: I use HikariCP by default in the Spring Boot 2.0.

Comment: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource?

Comment: Yes! Its com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.

Comment: Thank you Martin for accepting the answer! I hope that you will understand how connection pool is working and write a new implementation one day!

Comment: Spasibo, Pavel!:)

Comment: Pozhalusta, Martin! You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every connection pool manages connections differently. They have different strategies to grow the pool or to throw exceptions that there are no available connections.

Usually (but not a rule):

1. When Spring is started there are no active connections.
2. Yes, the first physical connection will be created when the pool is accessed the first time. After usage, it will stay in the pool in the idle state.
3. As far as there are idle connections, the pool will reuse them. Idle connections will be re-used for new requests.
4. If requests come and there no idle connections and maximum limit is reached, there are 2 strategies: grow the pool indefinitely or throw an exception. Throw an exception is a usual way to handle the situation. Requests that are currently processed by active connections will not be affected.
5. Idle connections can be destroyed after some time to avoid resource usage.

To understand the appropriate pool size is a matter of statistics and available resources. Again, maximum pool size can be increased or decreased based on the usage pattern and connection availability on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Every connection pool has it's own configuration options. Even different versions of the connection pool may have different options. Say, maxActive was used in the DBCP 1.x and it was renamed to maxTotal in the DBCP 2.x

Knowing what connection pool you are using is essential to configurate it properly. Some settings may work differently and there is no common answer to this question.

For your particular case, you are using HikariCP connection pool.
HikariCP has the following settings available:

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby

From the source code:

```
   // Properties changeable at runtime through the HikariConfigMXBean
   //
   private volatile String catalog;
   private volatile long connectionTimeout;
   private volatile long validationTimeout;
   private volatile long idleTimeout;
   private volatile long leakDetectionThreshold;
   private volatile long maxLifetime;
   private volatile int maxPoolSize;
   private volatile int minIdle;
   private volatile String username;
   private volatile String password;

   // Properties NOT changeable at runtime
   //
   private long initializationFailTimeout;
   private String connectionInitSql;
   private String connectionTestQuery;
   private String dataSourceClassName;
   private String dataSourceJndiName;
   private String driverClassName;
   private String jdbcUrl;
   private String poolName;
   private String schema;
   private String transactionIsolationName;
   private boolean isAutoCommit;
   private boolean isReadOnly;
   private boolean isIsolateInternalQueries;
   private boolean isRegisterMbeans;
   private boolean isAllowPoolSuspension;
   private DataSource dataSource;
   private Properties dataSourceProperties;
   private ThreadFactory threadFactory;
   private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor;
   private MetricsTrackerFactory metricsTrackerFactory;
   private Object metricRegistry;
   private Object healthCheckRegistry;
   private Properties healthCheckProperties;
```

It doesn't use maxActive property, so your question is not applicable to this connection pool.

In your case, you can remove this property as com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource is not using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this issue was more in general about the basic architecture of pools. Look at my questions. And: Privet iz Moskvi:)

Comment: Is the tomcat'  pool architecture so different from Hikaru's architecture or DBCP ?(for instance)

Comment: Yes, it's completely different source code and implementation. The only common is an interface. But an interface is not implementation :( Implementation is different, you can check the source code of both. That's the best way to understand how it works. The final source of truth :) But be aware that implementation may radically change between major versions. DBCP 2.x is implemented differently than DBCP 1.x.

Comment: I am in New York now :) But thank you for 'Privet' :) Privet from New York :)